# Unexpected aguments when saving a form in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to save form data using Django. My app is a very basic car maintenance app I am creating to learn Django.
Here is my Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from service.models import Service
from service.forms import oil_change

# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def service(request):

    obj = User
    obj = Service.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    temp = list(Service.objects.all())
    print("here")
    if temp:
        result = temp[0]
        return render(request, 'serviceT/service.html', {'object': obj, 'result': result})

    return render(request, 'serviceT/service.html', {'object': obj})


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def update_miles(request):
    obj = User
    obj = Service.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'object': obj}

    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        Service.objects.all().delete()
        form = oil_change(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
            miles = form.cleaned_data["miles"]
            last_change = form.cleaned_data["last_change"]
            reminder = form.cleaned_data["reminder"]

            next_change = reminder + miles

            oil_change(user=request.user, miles=miles, last_change=last_change, reminder=next_change).save()
            return render(request, 'serviceT/service.html', context)

    else:
        form = oil_change()
    return render(request, 'serviceT/miles.html', {'form': form})
```

The issue in on the line where I try to save the form.
oil_change(user=request.user....)

Here is my forms.py and models.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from django.forms import ModelForm
from service.models import Service

class oil_change(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ['miles', 'last_change', 'reminder']
        widgets = {
            'miles': forms.NumberInput(),
            'last_change': forms.NumberInput(),
            'reminder': forms.NumberInput()
        }
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.

class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    miles = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    last_change = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    reminder = models.IntegerField(default=5000, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

This is really throwing me through a loop because in my same program I have another view that saves the form in, as far as I can tell, the exact same way and it works no problem. Here is that view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from calculator.forms import Calculation
from calculator.models import Calculator

# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def calculator(request):

    obj = User
    obj = Calculator.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'object': obj}

    return render(request, 'calculatorT/calculator.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add_calculation(request):

        obj = User
        obj = Calculator.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {'object': obj}

        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            form = Calculation(request.POST)
            if (form.is_valid()):
                vehicle_name = form.cleaned_data["vehicle_name"]
                vehicle_price = form.cleaned_data["vehicle_price"]
                sales_tax = form.cleaned_data["sales_tax"]
                interest_rate = form.cleaned_data["interest_rate"]
                down_payment = form.cleaned_data["down_payment"]
                term = form.term = int(request.POST.get('term'))

                loan_amount = vehicle_price*(1+(sales_tax/100)) - down_payment
                interest_rate = interest_rate/100

                monthy_payment = (loan_amount*(interest_rate/12)/(1-(1+interest_rate/12)**-term))
                total_price = monthy_payment * term
                interest_rate=interest_rate*100

                Calculator(user=request.user, vehicle_name=vehicle_name, vehicle_price=vehicle_price,
                    sales_tax=sales_tax, interest_rate=interest_rate, down_payment=down_payment,
                    term=term, monthy_payment=monthy_payment, total_price=total_price).save()

                return render(request, 'calculatorT/calculator.html', context)
        else:
            form = Calculation()
        return render(request, 'calculatorT/new_calc.html', {'form': form})

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def delete_estimate(request, id):

    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        Calculator.objects.get(vehicle_name=id).delete()
        return redirect('/calculator/')

    return redirect('/calculator/')
```

The forms.py and models.py are also written the same as above, just with different fields. This is really throwing me for a loop. I don't understand why it works with one views but not the other.
Here is the traceback

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/miles

Django Version: 3.0.9
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home',
 'service',
 'login_join',
 'calculator']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nlopez/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/nlopez/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/nlopez/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/nlopez/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nlopez/Desktop/cins490/finalproject/service/views.py", line 39, in update_miles
    oil_change(user=request.user, miles=miles, last_change=last_change, reminder=next_change).save()

Exception Type: TypeError at /service/miles
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# you can't do this
oil_change(user=request.user, miles=miles, last_change=last_change, reminder=next_change)
```

A Django form expects form data in a dictionary. [See source code for `__init__` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/forms.py#L64), the first argument is called `data`, so when you pass `request.POST` to the form, the `request.POST` is passed in place of the `data` argument.

If you pass named arguments (as you're doing), then they will be used as separate arguments for the `__init__` method which is why you're getting that error.

Fix your error like this:

```
data = {'user': request.user, 'miles': miles, 'last_change': last_change, 'reminder': next_change}

oil_change(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def update_miles(request):
    obj = User
    obj = Service.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'object': obj}

    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        Service.objects.all().delete()
        form = oil_change(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
            miles = form.cleaned_data["miles"]
            last_change = form.cleaned_data["last_change"]
            reminder = form.cleaned_data["reminder"]

            next_change = reminder + miles

            form.save(user=request.user) # ------------------------- [Change]
            return render(request, 'serviceT/service.html', context)

    else:
        form = oil_change()
    return render(request, 'serviceT/miles.html', {'form': form})
```

I think error occurs cuz there is no field `user` in `oil_change`.

Your two `views` are little bit different cuz in other view you used `Calculator` which is `model` not `form` but you used `oil_change` `form` which have no `user` field.